# Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred + Ambiguous reference to member 'count'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am facing a strange error with that Swift code inside a View:

Swift file 1

```
[...]
    let cookingDifficulties: [String] = ["Very easy","Easy","Medium","Difficult"]
[...]
```

Swift file 2: that one compiles

```
[...]
    Picker(selection: $selectedCookingDifficulty, label: Text("")) {
                ForEach(0..<cookingDifficulties.count) {
                    Text(cookingDifficulties[$0])
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
[...]
```

Swift file 3: that one returns the Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred error

```
[...]
            HStack{
                Text("Difficulty: ")
                Picker(selection: $selectedCookingDifficulty, label: Text("")) {
                    ForEach(0..<cookingDifficulties.count) { //--> Ambiguous reference to member 'count'
                        Text(cookingDifficulties[$0]) //--> Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            }
[...]
```

I spent a couple of hours to search for an answer but without success.
Anyone would have a great idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both pickers essentially are the same and the first one compiles I strongly assume the error is actually at some other code in the view's body.

Also, the second failing picker code compiles just fine for me when put in a clean view's body.

The received error messages also suggest this (I have seen such errors when the error was way somewhere else.

I would comment parts above the failing picker code until it compiles.

FYI: 
The way you set up the `@State selectedDifficulty` does not set the selection initially. This does:

```
  Picker(selection: $selectedCookingDifficulty, label: Text("")) {
    ForEach(cookingDifficulties, id: \.self) {
      Text($0)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, you were right, the error was elsewhere... but the compiler wrongly highlighted this statement...